# Determine which button pressed in Save Panel in NSDocument based application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nssavepanel

How should I determine which button is pressed (save, Cancel) when the save dialog is dismissed in an NSDocument based application ? The save panel is the default provided by NSDocument when save is selected from menu.

I would like to have the chance to change some vars **before** - (BOOL)writeToURL:ofType:error: is invoked.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set an object as the save panel's delegate and implement the `‑panel:validateURL:error:` method. That method is called after the Save button is pressed but before the document is saved.

However, I'd question the need to do this. What sort of variables do you need to change only when the file is saved? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In the SavePanel and in an accessory view that I've added, I have an option to save the file under different encoding. The encoding value should only be used if the user presses the Save button. Note that the Document is reloaded with the new encoding after save as. I could use the encoding value selected in my accessory view in -writeToURL:ofType... but what if the user changes that value (in accessory view) and then disides to cancel? That value will stay there and if just "Save" is invoked (instead of "Save as") there will be a wrong encoding value. Any alternatives? Thanks for your answer!